# Count Frequency based on Bit Flag

Tags: sql

```
SELECT    

              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dicei.IsLocked ORDER BY DocumentInstanceChapterExpanded.PK_DocumentInstanceChapterExpanded)                 
             ,DocumentInstance.PK_DocumentInstance
             ,DocumentInstanceChapterExpanded.PK_DocumentInstanceChapterExpanded 
             ,dicei.IsLocked

FROM         DocumentInstance INNER JOIN
                      DocumentInstanceChapter ON DocumentInstance.PK_DocumentInstance = DocumentInstanceChapter.FK_DocumentInstance INNER JOIN
                      DocumentInstanceChapter AS DocumentInstanceChapter_1 ON 
                      DocumentInstanceChapter.PK_DocumentInstanceChapter = DocumentInstanceChapter_1.FK_DocumentInstanceChapter INNER JOIN
                      DocumentInstanceChapterExpanded ON 
                      DocumentInstanceChapter_1.PK_DocumentInstanceChapter = DocumentInstanceChapterExpanded.FK_DocumentInstanceChapter INNER JOIN
                      DocumentInstanceChapterExpanded AS DocumentInstanceChapterExpanded_1 ON 
                      DocumentInstanceChapter.PK_DocumentInstanceChapter = DocumentInstanceChapterExpanded_1.FK_DocumentInstanceChapter INNER JOIN
                      DocumentInstanceChapterExpandedItem AS dicei ON 
                      DocumentInstanceChapterExpanded.PK_DocumentInstanceChapterExpanded = dicei.FK_DocumentInstanceChapterExpanded
WHERE     (DocumentInstance.PK_DocumentInstance = 455) 
 AND DocumentInstanceChapterExpanded_1.PK_DocumentInstanceChapterExpanded = 50730
```

[image]

As you can see the picture what i wanted to do was add a Column which would indicate

```
**Result Expected**
ExpandeditemKey IsLocked     StatusColumn
50797               0         Mixed
50797               0         Mixed 
50797               1         Mixed
50797               1         Mixed
50797               1         Mixed
50798               1         Lock
50798               1         Lock
50798               1         Lock

If it contains 0 and 1 'Mixed'
If it contains 1 only  'Lock'
If it contains 0 only  'Unlock'
```

it does not necessary need to be string column, i tried using OverBy Clause if i can used Partition by for the Islock Bit Field but was not able to 
Thanks for having a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest usng MIN/MAX as window functions, then you can add a case expression that works across a partition. e.g.

```
SELECT
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dicei.IsLocked ORDER BY DocumentInstanceChapterExpanded.PK_DocumentInstanceChapterExpanded)
    , DocumentInstance.PK_DocumentInstance
    , DocumentInstanceChapterExpanded.PK_DocumentInstanceChapterExpanded
    , dicei.IsLocked
    , case when dicei.isLockedMin <> dicei.isLockedMax then 'Mixed'
           when dicei.isLockedMax = 0 then 'Unlocked'
           else 'Locked'
      end StatusColumn
FROM DocumentInstance
INNER JOIN DocumentInstanceChapter ON DocumentInstance.PK_DocumentInstance = DocumentInstanceChapter.FK_DocumentInstance
INNER JOIN DocumentInstanceChapter AS documentinstancechapter_1 ON DocumentInstanceChapter.PK_DocumentInstanceChapter = documentinstancechapter_1.FK_DocumentInstanceChapter
INNER JOIN DocumentInstanceChapterExpanded ON documentinstancechapter_1.PK_DocumentInstanceChapter = DocumentInstanceChapterExpanded.FK_DocumentInstanceChapter
INNER JOIN DocumentInstanceChapterExpanded AS documentinstancechapterexpanded_1 ON DocumentInstanceChapter.PK_DocumentInstanceChapter = documentinstancechapterexpanded_1.FK_DocumentInstanceChapter
INNER JOIN (
      select d.*
            , min(d.IsLocked) over(partition by d.FK_DocumentInstanceChapterExpanded) isLockedMin
            , max(d.IsLocked) over(partition by d.FK_DocumentInstanceChapterExpanded) isLockedMax
      from DocumentInstanceChapterExpandedItem d
      ) AS dicei ON DocumentInstanceChapterExpanded.PK_DocumentInstanceChapterExpanded = dicei.FK_DocumentInstanceChapterExpanded
WHERE (DocumentInstance.PK_DocumentInstance = 455)
AND documentinstancechapterexpanded_1.PK_DocumentInstanceChapterExpanded = 50730
```

edit, due to the bit column, case expressions were needed:

```
            , min(case when d.IsLocked = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by d.FK_DocumentInstanceChapterExpanded) isLockedMin
            , max(case when d.IsLocked = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by d.FK_DocumentInstanceChapterExpanded) isLockedMax
```

Comment: Thank you i have posted the result above . I didnt know how to add it in the comment section.

Comment: I have banged my head for 8 hours to get this sorted out using group by , cross join. I cannot thank you enough. All the best.

Comment: I hear you, and I know what it is like, so it's a pure pleasure to assist :) cheers.